# React-Bootstrap-Table2's cells are refreshing only after I go back into cell editing

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

So I have code similar to what is shown in the code sandbox link.
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-cloud-3n7t2?file=/src/App.js)

```
class CostPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};

    this.tableColumns = [
      { dataField: "name", text: "Product", editable: false },
      { dataField: "year1", text: "Year1", editable: true, type: "number" },
      { dataField: "year2", text: "Year2", editable: true, type: "number" }
    ];

    this.tableContents = [
      { id: 1, name: "Rollup", year1: 0, year2: 0, isParent: true },
      { id: 2, name: "Nintendo", year1: 10, year2: 20, isParent: false },
      { id: 3, name: "Xbox", year1: 30, year2: 40, isParent: false },
      { id: 4, name: "Playstation", year1: 50, year2: 60, isParent: false }
    ];

    this.displayTable = this.displayTable.bind(this);
    this.afterSaveCell = this.afterSaveCell.bind(this);

    this.UpdateRollup();
  }

  afterSaveCell(oldValue, newValue, row, column) {
    this.UpdateRollup();
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  // In reality this would sum the column vals, but this will work for now
  UpdateRollup() {
    this.tableContents[0]["year1"] += 1;
    this.tableContents[0]["year2"] += 1;
  }

  displayTable() {
    return (
      <BootstrapTable
        keyField="id"
        data={this.tableContents}
        columns={this.tableColumns}
        cellEdit={cellEditFactory({
          mode: "dbclick",
          autoSelectText: true,
          afterSaveCell: (oldValue, newValue, row, column) => {
            this.afterSaveCell(oldValue, newValue, row, column);
          }
        })}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="App">{this.displayTable()}</div>;
  }
}
```

**Goal**: When I go to update a cell's cost, I want to update another cell in the Rollup row after the value has been changed to the original cell.

**Expectation**: I would expect to see both the original cell change as well as the rollup value, but this is not the case.

**Reality**: I see the original value change, but not the rollup. I do see the rollup value update once I go back in to edit any of the cells where a value has changed(the rollup cells).

**Question**: Am I misusing the table in the react lifecycle? What would be the proper way to have the cell I am editing, and the rollup cells updated correctly in the table?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the issue. I had issue data was not loaded in table unless clicked on table sorting:

Changes i did:

Made componentDidMount call async and axios call inside this function await.

```html
async componentDidMount() {
  const {data} = await axios.get(url);
   this.setState({orders: data});
}
```

Comment: So to understand this correctly, you mount the table then update the data?